# Unable to open X display when launching Cinnamon

Tags: xorg, cinnamon

I installed Arch Linux and I'm unable to start Cinnamon.

I can use startx and it has that green-y interface. I've tried searching with not much luck.

I try to start it with `cinnamon`

```
Failed to init server
Unable to open X display
```

There is not logs when I start cinnamon, only when I use startx (even though it works)

`Failed to load module (module does not exist, 0)` for these: `nvidia`, `nv`, `modesetting`.

So I used `pacman -S nvidia` and got: `Nvidia-libgl and mesa-libgl are in conflict (libgl). Remove mesa-libgl?` So I prompted with `y`. Then `error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)`

Comment: how are you starting Cinnamon?

Comment: ps: welcome to Stack Exchange! just to let you know, when you answer that question, you should edit your question to include the additional information. you can find the edit button right below the tags.

Comment: I'm just typing `cinnamon`.

Comment: I reinstalled my NVIDIA drivers and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is the way you're starting Cinnamon.

When you type `cinnamon`, or `gnome-shell`, or `gedit`, or any other X app (a.k.a. X client), it tries to connect to an X server (started either by `startx` or a display manager). If it can't find one, it will fail. This is 100% expected.

You need to either `startx` or use a [display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager) to use Cinnamon. I've never heard of a desktop environment that starts the X server for you, except for XFCE (with `startxfce`).

Comment: Understood. I got nvidia installed and tried `startx cinnemon` and it brought up: `waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.t shell already was /usr/bin/xtermxt`.    So I opened Xorg.0.log and the only errors inside were server terminated successfully. I also have GNOME, so I tried to run that too which just brought me with a black screen.

Comment: @user2896137 I've seen that issue too before, where `startx foo` launches `foo` but it terminates immediately. I don't know how to fix it, though, since I use a display manager.

Comment: What display manager would you recommend and how do I use/install it?

Comment: by the way, if you found that this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check icon below the arrows on the left-hand side. or if you just found it useful, you can click the up arrow to show your thanks.

Comment: @user2896137 see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager. I can't tell you which to pick, as an Arch user, you have to do that for yourself :)

Comment: I wouldn't use LXDM. See https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2013-September/034132.html

Comment: @user2896137  You'll need to install xterm using `pacman -S xterm` then it should work =)  Do `startx` and then `cinnamon-session` from xterm

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or modify an .xinitrc file in your home directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi
exec cinnamon-session
```

Then reboot your computer and try using `startx` or `xinit`. At that point it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon installation would have created the Light Display Manager service (lightdm.service), which will need to be enabled as follows:

```
systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

Next do the following or reboot to start Cinnamon automatically without doing **startx**

```
systemctl restart lightdm.service
```